# maven release:branch updates developerConnection in pom trunk to be the branch url

Tags: java, maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to have a build and release strategy that works like this:

- develop in trunk
- when sprint is over, copy trunk to a branch using release:branch to allow the next sprint to start on trunk
- deploy the branch to a QA environment
- fix any bugs in the branch
- Once QA says it's ok, do a release:prepare and release:perform on that branch
- Deploy that release to pre-prod, test, and then deploy to production.

Everything seems to be ok except that it's updating the developerConnection tag in the trunk pom to be the url of the branch. Trunk should remain like this:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn:9880/project/Utils/trunk</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

But instead its getting updated to this:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn:9880/project/Utils/branches/1.0-SNAPSHOT</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

I assume this is happening since the release:branch goal is making this change in anticipation of using release:prepare and release:perform where once of those will update the pom in trunk back to the proper developerConnection url.

Is there any way to prevent this? So that the developerConnection in trunk stays as trunk but the branch developerConnection is updated to be the branch?

Comment: release command dnt update the URL of SCM.

Comment: @Oggie How does you command look like you've used to create the branch by `mvn release:branch` supplemental parameters?

Comment: What version of maven-release-plugin?

Comment: the command is: -Dresume=false release:branch -DbranchName=${project.version} -DremoteTagging=false -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=true   I'm using version 2.4.1 of the release plugin.

Comment: So you are blaming release plugin to name a branch like `1.0-SNAPSHOT` which you defined on the command line (`... -DbranchName=${project.version} ...`? What is your problem? I would suggest to name a branch more like `B_1.0` or something similiar but i don't see the problem? And of course it needs to change the information in the SCM area, cause if you like to make a release from the branch it must have the correct relation to the branch to create the Subversion Tag from the branch instead from the trunk.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the branch having the name 1.0-SNAPSHOT. Nor do I have a problem with the developerConnection tag having that URL in the branch. I just don't want that URL in trunk.